# Zune Marketplace showing apps for Zune HD and not Windows Phone

Tags: zune

Zune Marketplace showing apps for Zune HD and not Windows Phone

I don't own a Zune HD, but a Windows Phone. Yet, the marketplace is showing me apps for a Zune HD:
[image: Zune Marketplace]

The marketplace used to show Windows Phone apps, how can I see them again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft removed the option to download apps from the Zune client with the Marketplace changes they implemented yesterday.

The reason for this is a security and performance reason stated in the announcement linked below

here is the official announcement:
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/04/24/two-marketplace-changes-and-how-they-affect-you.aspx

Comment: I see, the article says it's been replaced by the [web Marketplace](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps). Weird though, he doesn't explain how the change improves performance or security.

Comment: it means you never install apps through zune.  one less hoop to jump through, one less place for an app package to temporarily live, etc.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

That was a change made by Microsoft yesterday. Don't understand the meaning for this but it's true, Marketplace from Zune in PC is gone

Comment: This is true; you can only browse, install and buy apps for Windows Phone from the phone itself or the web Marketplace now. Zune is only used for media management on your PC, synching media to your phone and updating your phone's firmware.